# Rails Oauth2 authorization modify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, oauth-2.0

Recently, I want to implement an authentication system that allow other companies create bunch of users in our service.

I read many references about `Oauth2` flow like this.
[image]

But I think my authentication system now would not contain the step (B), (C) and (D).

However, I think in far future, my service should surpport 3rd party access, which means I need the step (B) to (D).

My question is that, is there a greater implementation that match my first require? Is there a easier way to scale authentication system?

BTW I use `Rails` to create this backend system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the best way for you is to implement full specification according to RFC - it will protect you from lots of problems in the future, and will allow you easily open your app for third-party access without pain (for you and for third-party developers).

If you are using Oauth2 on Rails, best place to start - gem `omniauth`, which is community-standart for oauth.

Comment: But what if I don't need the Resource owner?  I just need to give the authorization to some company as our partner?

Comment: It also depends :) For example, in my case, afer a year after realization of oAuth, we found, that we must split our application and divide auth system from the rest of the app. We automatically received Reource owner :) If you know, that you won't need recource owner - don't implement it. But i still recommend you  to have a look at omniauth.

Comment: Thanks, I've read about `omniauth`. I probably remove the part of `grant code`.